# MySQL Error #1442 - Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql

I created two tables in MySQL:
**accident:**

````
``CREATE TABLE `accident_main` (
  `accident_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `square_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driver_id` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `cause_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`accident_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `accident_id` (`accident_id`),
  KEY `square_id` (`square_id`,`cause_id`),
  KEY `cause_id` (`cause_id`),
  KEY `side_number` (`side_number`),
  KEY `line_id` (`line_id`),
  KEY `driver_id` (`driver_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `accident_main_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cause_id`) REFERENCES `causes` (`cause_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `accident_main_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`side_number`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`side_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `accident_main_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`line_id`) REFERENCES `linie` (`line_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=688 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci ```
and a triggered after update accident table.
````

and **causes** **table**:

```
 CREATE TABLE `causes` (
  `cause_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cause_description` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `amount_of_accidents` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cause_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER acc_main_update BEFORE UPDATE ON accident_main FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        IF OLD.cause_id <> NEW.cause_id THEN
  
    UPDATE causes
        SET causes.amount_of_accidents = causes.amount_of_accidents -1
        WHERE causes.cause_id = OLD.cause_id;
    UPDATE causes
        SET causes.amount_of_accidents = causes.amount_of_accidents + 1
        WHERE causes.cause_id = NEW.accident_main.cause_id;
    END
        IF ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to update accident table I get the error message:
#1442 - Can't update table 'causes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
Can anybody tell me why it happens and my trigger doesn't work properly?

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing a count over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the count, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: I tested your code you show above but I get no error when updating `accident_main`. I think you have some other trigger you have not shown us.

Comment: Yes, the trigger passed but if I want to update accident main e.g. UPDATE     accident_main SET     accident_main.cause_id = 1 WHERE     accident_id = 2 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM causes WHERE causes.cause_id = 1); 
This is the only trigger I have here. I know that data is redundant, but it's only academic project and I have to use trigger

Comment: I do not receive for know an error if I use simple update, e.g. `UPDATE
    accident_main
SET
    accident_main.cause_id = 10
WHERE
    accident_id = 2`, but I receive this error message when I validate the data: 
`UPDATE
    accident_main
SET
    accident_main.cause_id = 10
WHERE
    accident_id = 2 AND EXISTS(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        causes
    WHERE
        causes.cause_id = 2
); `.
 Does it happen, because I want to check if data exists in the table which is used by trigger, am I right?